# VueJS deployed production build showing broken png images

Tags: html, vue.js, deployment

I've ran `npm run build` and this generates a dist folder with the static assets such as images. I'm using history mode on vue router.

Here's what the HTML for the image looks like:

[image]

Here's what the dist folder looks like:

[image]

Now after deploying the site, the images are broken:

[image]

However, the img src is correct:

[image]

So what's the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that the problem is related to your routes and that the relative paths are not working from routes.

If your app is shown on root directory `/`, the relative image path would work, but because (and it's guess) your route changes the current path to something like `/sales`, the relative path no longer works.

You may be able to fix this just by making sure that you use the relative path.

for example, if you're using a vue-cli-3 generated project, check the `vue.config.js` file and make sure you don't have the `publicPath` set, because it defaults to `/`.

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./", // <= this will use relative path
};
```

Comment: I've added the HTML for the image. I am using routes and relative image paths so your hypothesis seems sound. I am using a vue-cli-3 generated project. I don't have the public path set. So what is the solution? To set the publicPath to "./" ?

Comment: I've added the publicPath as "./" however it still isn't working

Comment: try using `/` instead of `./`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change paths in the index.js containing routes to your destination folder for example: dist.

As a publicPath I set `./` as *Daniel* mentioned.

This helped me but still, I've just started to learn VueJS so it might not to be the best solution.

```
    const routes = [
  {
    path: '/dist/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/dist/map',
    name: 'Map',
    component: Map
  },
  {
    path: '/dist/store',
    name: 'Store',
    component: Store
  }
]
```